# how to hide my client's password in API response

Tags: javascript, express

I am just a beginner at Javascript & MERN. I am trying to create a small social media app, and in my sign up api, I gave a response of the user's info. I couldn't segregate and hide the password.

here is the code

```
userRouter.post("/signUp", async (req, res) => {
    
    const {name, userName, email, password} = req.body

    const existingUser = await userSchema.findOne({email: email})
    const SameUserName = await userSchema.findOne({userName: userName})
    if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(406).send({
            message: `sorry, an account with email: ${email} has already been created.`
        })
    } else if (SameUserName) {
        return res.status(406).send({
            message: `sorry, user name taken. Try another one...`
        })
    }

    const newUser = new userSchema({
        name,
        userName,
        email,
        password
    })
    console.log(newUser)

    try {
        await newUser.save()
        res.status(201).send({
            message: `Account successfully created!`,
            user: newUser
        })
    } catch (err) {
        res.send({
            message:`Something went wrong`,
        })
    }
})
```

So, how can I send the user info without the password?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @Leal_em you should really refactor your code. If you paste the actual code on your question it's going to be easier to help you doing that.

Comment: Somehow, this code looks like plaintext passwords in databases, an old friend.

Comment: `sorry, an account with email: ${email} has already been created.` - this can be used to check if someEmail, not necessarily *my* email, is signed up with your system.  This might not be ideal, because privacy.

Comment: @James isn't that quite normal? What else could be done?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze Use a generic error message, take a look [here](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.md#authentication-and-error-messages)

Comment: @james that's for authentication and i completely agree. But if you create an account you probably have to tell the user that this email adress already registered, haven't you?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze it's similar for sign-up, see the recommendations [here](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.md#account-creation)

Comment: @james thx, I overlooked this section.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the comment I left below, here is what you can do.

*Refactoring of your code is must thou*.

```
try {
 const userSaved = await newUser.save();
 delete userSaved.password // assuming this is the property name
 return res.status(201).send({ message: 'Account created successfully', user: userSaved })
}
```

you could also just:

```
try {
 const userSaved = await newUser.save();
 delete userSaved.password // assuming this is the property name
 return userSaved;
}
```

In this case you handle the message and everything on the front-end.

Comment: okay, thank you bruh!

Comment: My first post.... I will refactor from now on, sorry

Comment: Awesome! One more thing, you don't need to execute to requests on your DB. In the beginning of the request you do a findOne using the email and another using the username. On your entity you can add the `@Unique` decorator to it. This will make sure a certain value is always unique.

Oh! Don't forget to hit the "check" icon on the response :) All the best!

Comment: Just implemented ur suggestions....Tnx again

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to implement the [toJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior) and [transform](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematypeoptions_SchemaTypeOptions-transform) methods on your schema. This will allow you to 'intercept' schema objects as they are created, and as they are serialized and sent to the client.

Here's an example:

Schema:

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const schema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        userName: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            type: String
        }
    },
    {
        // here, we implement the `toJSON` method to serialize the user object sans password, __v;
        // we'll also convert the mongo-specific `_id` property to a db-agnostic format
        toJSON: {
            transform(_, ret) {
                ret.id = ret._id;

                delete ret.password;
                delete ret._id;
                delete ret.__v;
            }
        }
    }
);

// this is our user schema, used to initialize new user objects before we persist them in the db
const User = model('User', schema);
```

```
userRouter.post('/signUp', async (req, res) => {
    // grab the inputs - we do *not* at this time know whether any of these are valid - they must be validated
    const { name, userName, email, password } = req.body;

    // validate the email format, performing checks for any requirements you wish to enforce
    if (!email) {
        // error response
    }

    // now, we check if the email is already in-use
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: `sorry, an account with email: ${email} has already been created.`
        });
    }

    // validate userName format here
    if (!userName) {
        // error response
    }

    // notice we don't bother making this query until `existingUser` check has passed
    // this way we don't incur needless computation
    const sameUserName = await User.findOne({ userName });
    if (sameUserName) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: `sorry, user name taken. Try another one...`
        });
    }

    // validate name and password and handle accordingly here
    if (!name || ...) {
        // error response
    }

    // assuming all is well, we create a new user with the schema
    // think of the schema as a template
    const newUser = new User({ name, userName, email, password });

    // save the new user
    await newUser.save().catch((ex) => {
        // error response
    });

    res.status(201).send({
        message: `Account successfully created!`,
        user: newUser
    });
});
```

You might also look into [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/), a middleware that handles much of the request body validation for you.

Comment: As an aside, a 406 status code is not appropriate here; it should be used when the server cannot respond with the accept-header specified in the request. Use a 400.

Comment: Thank you Bruh, you made a whole tutorial just for me! Will go through the validation. Thank you!